# Getting JMeter to Authenticate with Kerberos

Tags: jmeter, kerberos

I have so problems trying to authenticate with Kerberos through JMeter. I've followed some setup guide on different sites but still JMeter failed to authenticate. All HTTP requests that I recorded failed during playback with code **401**.

Before this, our test server uses both Kerberos and NTLM for authentication and the tests went fine. Until this month when the security team enforce Kerberos as the only security.

---

On JMeter command prompt screen, everytime I run the test this is displayed:

> [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal **MyUserName** to Subject
>   Commit Succeeded

---

The HTTP requests still comeback with 401

Under My Test Plan I've added:
 - HTTP Authorization Manager
 - HTTP Request Defaults
 - Header Manager
 - Cookie Manager

---

**Authorization stored in Authorization manager**

|| ...URL... ||  ---username-- ||  password || -----Domain---- || ----Realm----- || Mechanism ||

|| ...URL... ||  *myUserName* ||  *********** || ***COMDOMAIN*** || **DEPT.COMPANY.COM** || KERBEROS ||

---

I've edited krb5.conf to look as follows:

> [libdefaults]
>   default_tkt_enctypes = omitted
>   default_tgs_enctypes = omitted
>   forwardable = omitted
>   dns_lookup_kdc = true
>   dns_lookup_realm = true
>   udp_preference_limit = 1
>   
>   default_realm = **DEPT.COMPANY.COM**
>   
>   [realms]
>   **DEPT.COMPANY.COM**= {
>   kdc = TEST-SPACE.dev.company.com
>   admin_server = TEST-SPACE.dev.company.com
>   }
>   
>   [domain_realm]
>   ***COMDOMAIN*** = **DEPT.COMPANY.COM**

The **kdc** and **admin_server** were provided by the security guy. I don't have any access to the server security.

EDIT 1:
Update on this question. So I reenabled the prompt for kerberos credential to manually input my credential to the JMeter test and get the following:

```
KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\myadusername\krb5cc_MyADusername
LSA: Found Ticket
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found PrincipalName
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found EncryptionKey
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found TicketFlags
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found KerberosTime
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found String
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue constructor
LSA: Found Ticket constructor
LSA: Found PrincipalName constructor
LSA: Found EncryptionKey constructor
LSA: Found TicketFlags constructor
LSA: Found KerberosTime constructor
LSA: Finished OnLoad processing

Acquire default native Credentials
Found no TGT's in LSA
Kerberos username [MyADusername]: myadusername
Kerberos password for myadusername:
KdcAccessibility: reset
KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\myadusername\krb5cc_MyADusername
Acquire default native Credentials
Found no TGT's in LSA
```

**Sidenotes:** I looked up some online helps and have created the REG_SZ registry called allowtgtsessionkey default to 1 in regedit but to no avail.

Also regarding the same issue, I think it might be **keytab** related however my knowledge of keytab is limited. So I can login to the website normally, I just cannot get JMeter to get through Kerberos.

Comment: I just looked through the logs again, and I see this warning:
`HttpAuthenticator: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))`
But in JMeter system.properties, I've already added the lines below:
`java.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf `
`java.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf`

Comment: Read HTTPCLIENT-1625, JMeter is also affected. At best, your Fiddler as a proxy and it will do the SPNEGO auth